# can't include js file in pyramid project

Tags: javascript, templates, pyramid

I'm trying to use an external js file to use in my pyramid project.
I found this solution but i can't seem to get it work.
The js files i want to include are in C:\env\uza\uza\static\js
project name = uza.

In my template i use this to call the script:

```
<script type="text/js" src="${request.static_url('uza:static/js/fabtabulous.js')}" />  
<script type="text/js" src="${request.static_url('uza:static/js/tablekit.js')}" />
```

my init.py looks like this:

```
config.add_static_view('static', 'static', cache_max_age=3600)
```

When i navigate to the page in my browser it just gives me the pyramid sidebar in raw html code. I know it's a stupid mistake i made somewhere but i can't seem to find it. Is annyone able to help me with this.

**EDIT:**
I uploaded a pdf to give a better understanding of the problem i'm having.
ps: there are no errors in console.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6752022/problem.pdf

**EDIT:**
I made a new project using the sqlalchemy scaffold.
The changes I made are:
- include this line in the mytemplate.pt

```
<script type="text/js" src="${request.static_url('javascript:static/js/tette.js')}" /> 

<input type="button" onclick="popup()" value="Click Me!">
```

- i didn't change annything else because i don't think anny other changes need to be made in the scaffold.

- my tette.js file looks like this:

  function popup() {
  alert("Hello World")
  }

This is the output i have before including the js file. (deleted a few divs)
[image]

And this is after.
[image]

what am I doing wrong ? thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you able to post a live link, screenshot, or the actual code?

Comment: i forgot to make my scripts 'code' so it didn't show up in my previous post. now editted.

Comment: In your console log (i.e., when I'm developing locally it runs from 'pserve' and everything is logged to the terminal window) does it show any errors?

Comment: You're gonna need to show more code than that.

Comment: editted the post, thanks for your time

Comment: still doesn't work I editted the post with my other findings

Comment: What happens if you change your 'type="text/js"' to 'type="text/javascript"'?

Comment: same thing, doesn't change annything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you back it out to a point to where the pyramid sidebar looks and works correctly, and isn't raw HTML?

Your init.py line looks correct.  Then in your templates you can get at whatever is in the 'static' folder like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${request.static_url('myproject:static/style.css')}">
<!--[if lte IE 6]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${request.static_url('myproject:static/ie6.css')}" type="text/css" media="screen"
      charset="utf-8"/>
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="${request.static_url('myproject:static/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js')}"></script>
```

Comment: yeah, the funny part is that when i include a css file it works fine. but when i try to include a js file it just crashes.
The working version is before I include the js files. So i know my error is somewhere there :p

Comment: i edditted my post, should be more clear now. thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

it's as Peter Tirrell says.
I didn't say the type was javascript.